# Problem uploading .docx through html form

Tags: php, html, apache, forms, docx

I've made a simple form, with the proper enctype for uploading files. When i try to upload a .docx everything works fine in IE 8 and Safari, but in Firefox or IE 7 or 6 i can't even click submit, nothing happens! Could this still be a server issue? It's an apache server.

Everything works fine if i choose to upload a .doc file

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post" action="index.php">
    <input name="file" type="file" />
    <input type="submit" name="btnSubmit"  value="Submit"/>
</form>
```

Comment: Do you mean nothing happens when you click the button to submit the form, or that you can't actually click the "submit" button for some reason?

Comment: I click the submit button, something seems to happen in the progress bar but the page doesn't reload.

Comment: http://www.storaprimarvardspriset.se/#tavla <- you can try yourself there

Answer (score 0):

I tested your form in my Wamp2.0 with IE7 and Firefox,and it works fine.I don't think it could be the server issue since the form works well in you IE8.Perhaps you should standardize your html code,or check you browsers.

Comment: i've checked my html, and it validates fine although it's not as simple as above. And it's not only for me so it's not my browsers.